# cannot access database using php class

Tags: php, database, class

I created a class to access my database. The simplified class is following (I named it dbaccess.php)

```
class dbaccess {
function read($db) {
    $con = mysqli_connect($db);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM equipment");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $print = $print . $row['ID'] . " " . $row['name'] . " " . $row['new_price'] . " " . $row['residual_value'] . "<br>";
        }
    echo $print;
    mysqli_close($con);
    }
}
```

To access the class, I use this code

```
include './dbaccess.php';
//define db address
$add = '"localhost","myuser","mypassword","mydbname"';
$db = new dbaccess;
$db->read($add);
```

This code resulting

```
Failed to connect to MySQL: Unknown MySQL server host '"localhost","myuser","mypassword","mydbname"'(2)
```

I don't know how to fix it, can anyone here help me?

Comment: You need to pass each value in as a separate parameter, not as string of parameters.

Comment: it is clear but I don't think I can't define all parameter in one string

Comment: that is correct ... you cannot. you have to have 4 different arguments for your read method, $host, $user, $password, $db, when you call mysqli_connect pass each of these arguments in separately. Currently you are passing a single string argument in so it's trying to connect to a database on `"localhost","myuser","mypassword","mydbname"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing a single string to `mysqli_connect`.  You need to pass `"localhost"`, `"myuser"`,... as separate variables.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar with yours, download my files from dropbox and have a look inside
[DB Connect](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ukje669u9g7s6r5/dbconnect)

Comment: Great, you did it three years ago. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
class dbaccess {
    function read($db) {
        $con = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $dbname);
(...)
```

Then in your code, you should divide the parameters.

```
include './dbaccess.php';
//define db address
$db = new dbaccess;
$db->read("localhost","myuser","mypassword","mydbname");
```

<kbd>[**REF**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a better idea to store your host, username, password and database in separate variables like this:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "myuser";
$pass = "mypassword";
$data = "mydbname";
$db = new dbaccess(); // <-- It's good practice to use parentheses in the constructor statement.
$db->read($host,$user,$pass,$data);
```

And then the implementation of your `dbaccess` class could be more like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$data);
```

This is because the [`mysqli_connect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) function takes the host, username, etc. as **separate parameters**, not as a single string.